# namespace removal of xml

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I am getting below XML as source and have to convert by adding segments. But also the namespace added in root node has to be removed. But unable to remove the namespace.

can someone please share me where to add to the XSLT.

Source XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <Header 
                      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <Main>
                            <Parent2>
                                <status>12</status>
                                <statusmsg>Helo</statusmsg>
                            </Parent2>
                            <Parent3>
                                <Child1>112</Child1>
                                <Child2>Hai</Child2>
                            </Parent3>
                            <Parent4>
                                <Child3>Valley</Child3>
                                <Parent5>
                                    <Child7>Kind</Child7>
                                    <Child8>Pls</Child8>
                                </Parent5>
                            </Parent4>
                        </Main>
                    </Header>
```

Target XML :

```
 <Header>
                        <Main Mainattribute="1">
                            <Parent2 childattribute="1">
                                <status>12</status>
                                <statusmsg>Helo</statusmsg>
                            </Parent2>
                            <Parent3 childattribute="1">
                                <Child1>112</Child1>
                                <Child2>Hai</Child2>
                            </Parent3>
                            <Parent4 childattribute="1">
                                <Child3>Valley</Child3>
                                <Parent5>
                                    <Child7>Kind</Child7>
                                    <Child8>Pls</Child8>
                                </Parent5>
                            </Parent4>
                        </Main>
                    </Header>
```

XSLT Tried  from below link: 
                    [Populate Attribute and values to all parent nodes of the XML file from 4th parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515275/populate-attribute-and-values-to-all-parent-nodes-of-the-xml-file-from-4th-paren)

```
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:template match="Main">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Mainattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="parent_mode"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="*" mode="parent_mode">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="childattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="*">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove xmlns from XML using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157946/remove-xmlns-from-xml-using-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

An unused namespace declaration should not really cause any problems. But if you did want to get rid of it, in XSLT 1.0, you will have to create a new element, with `xsl:element` rather than using `xsl:copy` as the latter will copy the namespace declarations to.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Main">
        <Main>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="Mainattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="parent_mode"/>
        </Main>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="parent_mode">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="childattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you could use XSLT 2.0, you could add `copy-namespaces` to the `xsl:copy` instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Main">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="Mainattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="parent_mode"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="parent_mode">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="childattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No, not working. i have already tried that. the namespace has shifted from Header node to Main node. is there a way that we can hard delete the namespace.

Comment: I tested it at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtz and it gives the expected results. Did you ensure all instances of `<xsl:copy>` are replaced with `<xsl:element>`? Also what XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: i am trying to convert in https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output also our system is compatible with 1.0 and 2.0 as well. but not deleting the namespace. So cant we delete in a hardway as such. thank you

Comment: Sorry, it was XSLT1.0 but when i changed the code to element, it gives success but not creating attributes for parent_mode.

Comment: Which attributes is it not creating?

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler approach for XSLT 2.0 which is to use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/" copy-namespaces="no"/>
```

which does a deep copy dropping all unused namespaces.